# Polymer 1.0 Dependencies Conflict

Tags: jquery, bower, polymer-1.0

I have a jQuery dependency on my web component written in Polymer 1.0.

What happens if the user has a different version of jQuery installed? (e.g. the WC needs 1.9 and user has 2.2 installed, or vice versa) jQuery's structural hierarchy is changed between those versions. One needs `jquery/dist/...` the other one has no `dist` folder.

In my case Bower asks for dependency resolution which will determine which version will get picked, and I have no control over which version will ultimately get installed.

Comment: Have a look at `jQuery.noConflict()` [here](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.noconflict/)

Comment: I don't think that's my issue though, my issue is primarily pointing to a non-existing file depending on the version installed on the user, resulting in a 404 not found.